# Code for filtering products by attributes?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I have created a `brand.phtml` file in my custom theme. I want to write the code for getting products having specified attribute value.

Comment: You can try this for getting product attribute wise
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', 'attribute_value')
;

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Now you should have all the active and visible products in the `$collection` variable

Comment: its not working

Comment: what happens?. Also make sure that you attribute is marked as "used in product listing".

Comment: <?php
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('brand', array('eq' => 'Sony'))
;

Comment: instead of `Sony` you have to use the brand value id

Comment: @Marius your last two lines of code are deprecated! Status and visibility are not added anymore to the collection, quoted out in their belonging functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sAttributeName = 'brand';
$mOptionValue = 'Sony';
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        $sAttributeName,
        array(
            'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute($sAttributeName)
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId($mOptionValue)
        )
    );
```